# Is it possible to use firebase phone authenication using ionic 3?

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

I am trying to implement "firebase phone authentication" for my ionic 3 `Android` app. But, i really don't know is it possible to do it ? I have searched for it but there are not any plugin available which does support it.

Please , correct me and draw me to right direction. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/jestcastro/cordova-plugin-firebase#f778505942bbf7518df75545c6a6b32efa4d5229?

Comment: i have tried this plugin  ,but it only works on PWA app i guess.

Comment: Please, correct me if i am wrong.